# SQL `NULL` read at column 1 (JDBC type null) but mapping is to a non-Option type

Tags: scala, quill, doobie, quill.io

I want select the max value using this query (all fields in table are not null):

```
dc.run(quote {
    query[SchemaInfo]
      .filter(_.subjectName == lift(subject))
      .map(_.version)
      .max
  }).map(_.map(_ + 1).getOrElse(1))
```

I know, that table may be empty, so i use this: `map(_.map(_ + 1).getOrElse(1))`.

The problem is that this query produces this error:

> SQL `NULL` read at column 1 (JDBC type null) but mapping is to a
>   non-Option type; use Option here. Note that JDBC column indexing is
>   1-based. 
>   doobie.util.invariant$NonNullableColumnRead: SQL `NULL` read
>   at column 1 (JDBC type null) but mapping is to a non-Option type; use
>   Option here. Note that JDBC column indexing is 1-based.

How to fix it?
Without quill (using pure doobie) the same query working correctly

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I know that you probably got the answer already, but I will leave my comment here so that it hopefully help someone in the future.

so the problem is in line 
`query[SchemaInfo]`
as the record may not exist it should be mapped into
`query[Option[SchemaInfo]].unique`

Comment: Tricky, since the [BOD](https://tpolecat.github.io/doobie/docs/04-Selecting.html#reading-rows-into-collections) says `.option` "returns an Option, raising an exception if there is more than one row returned" (rather than "unless exactly one row is returned") implying that it does *not* raise an exception if there is fewer than one row returned.